# how to read and parse contents of text file into a Dictionary in Swift(CreateML)

Tags: swift, file, dictionary, createml

How can I read a dictionary from file? 
for example my text file look like this:

`[“book": [-0.33568978, -0.42831486],...]`

and i want to read it and put in a dictionary

`let myVector = [String:[Double]]()`

Comment: you mean `[String:[Double]]`. This looks like a JSON string. Take a look at `JSONDecoder`

Comment: What’s the hard part? Show some code and explain the difficulty.

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus, that was a great tip!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for anyone else who try to import their own custom embedding  with CreateML.

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport
import CreateML

do {
    let fileUrl = PlaygroundSupport.playgroundSharedDataDirectory.appendingPathComponent("resultsmall.json")
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileUrl)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let json = try decoder.decode([String: [Double]].self, from: data)

    let embedding = try MLWordEmbedding(dictionary: json)
    try embedding.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: "~/Desktop/WordEmbedding.mlmodel"))

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```